# Why is skew value calculated with excel sheet different from value calculated with pyspark/scipy

Tags: excel, pandas, pyspark, scipy

Calculating skew using scipy.stats

```
from scipy.stats import skew

val = [120.7, 120.5, 120.4, 120.2, 120.1]
skew(val)

0.13802317223314806
```

Calculating skew using excel, arranged the values in each row in one column and used skew function

```
=SKEW(A1:A5)

0.2057527971
```

Why is there a difference in skew value?
The same happens with pandas and pyspark. While calculating skew with pyspark it gives same result as scipy and when calculated with pandas it gives same result as excel

Comment: Apparently, the equivalent function in Excel would be `SKEW.P`

Answer (score 2):

This is likely the difference between a *biased* and *unbiased* calculation of the skewness. The [scipy implementation of skew](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skew.html) is biased by default. When you give an extra keyword `bias=False` you get the unbiased result:

```
from scipy.stats import skew

val = [120.7, 120.5, 120.4, 120.2, 120.1]
skew(val, bias=False)
>>0.20575279705565366
```

The Excel implementation and pandas implementation are both unbiased by default. I haven't checked the pyspark version, but my guess is that it is biased by default.